# Binding events to table cells using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my markup:

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <div>
        <table></table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table></table>
    </div>
    ....
</div>
```

I need to to register `mouseenter` event on all `td`s of all the tables (that are present inside each `div`).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $allTds = $('#divContainer').find("tr").find("td");
    ...
    SomeFunction();
});

function SomeFunction(){
   $allTds.on({
       mouseenter: function (e) {
           alert('hover');
       }
   });
}
```

But I don't get any alerts.

Comment: Well I don't see any `<td>`s in your markup example .. arey ou sure they exist?

Comment: @Explosion Pills, they are dynamically added. In firebug, I see the collection of `td`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your event handlers aren't being bound is that the `<td>` elements don't exist when you enter the document ready handler.

You should use event delegation for this. For example

```
window.jQuery(function($) {
    $('#divContainer').on({
        mouseenter: function(e) {
            alert('hover');
        }
    }, 'td');
});
```

This way, it's the `#divContainer` element that listens for the events and acts on them if they originate from a `<td>`.

See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

You also had a scoping problem where the `$allTds` variable is only defined in the document ready handler and is not in scope of the `SomeFunction` function.

Answer (score 3):

They way you apply the event listener is weird.

```
$('#divContainer').on('mouseenter','td',function() {
    alert('mouse entered');
});
```

Also: It's good that you cache the td elements, but why don't you stick with something more simple?

```
$allTd = $('#divContainer td');
```